# Problem with custom_language in pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I have tried many time to set a custom language for my captcha bot but when i put the .text or any else function equal a string I got an error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```
options = CaptchaOptions()
options.generator = "keyzend"
options.custom_language.text = "example"
options.timeout = 120
captcha_manager = CaptchaManager(bot.get_me().id, default_options=options)
```

Doc: https://github.com/SwissCorePy/pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA#customlanguage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomLanguage is a class like CaptchaOptions. You would have to instantiate a custom language object from the CustomLanguage class.

```
my_lang = CustomLanguage()
my_lang.text = "example"
```

and so on for your other attributes. Don't forget to set your custom_language:

```
options.custom_language = my_lang
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code at the bottom and try running:

```
options = CaptchaOptions()
options.generator = "keyzend"
options.text = "example"
options.timeout = 120
captcha_manager = CaptchaManager(bot.get_me().id, default_options=options)
```